# limit filename matches that start a particular way

Tags: php, regex

I have thousands of files in a directory that i am running a batch script on to process.

The relevant files all start with XX-XX-XX (at least one integer, but no more than two, with underscores separating the three numbers)

I used txt2re to create this:

```
 $txt='1-2-3';

  $re1='(\\d+)';    # Integer Number 1
  $re2='(-)';   # Any Single Character 1
  $re3='(\\d+)';    # Integer Number 2
  $re4='(-)';   # Any Single Character 2
  $re5='(\\d+)';    # Integer Number 3

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $int1=$matches[1][0];
      $c1=$matches[2][0];
      $int2=$matches[3][0];
      $c2=$matches[4][0];
      $int3=$matches[5][0];
      print "($int1) ($c1) ($int2) ($c2) ($int3) \n";
  }
```

Is it possible to get a slightly more compact version of this, that I can compare to the filename in a single function.

Comment: I 'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Do you want a boolean test or something else? In any case, the correct regex would be `^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
"/^\d\d?-\d\d?-\d\d?/"
```

If the digits are separated by underscores use `_` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate everything together at declaration.

```
$txt='1-2-3';

$re = '/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/is';

if ($c=preg_match_all ($re, $txt, $matches))
{
    $int1=$matches[1][0];
    $int2=$matches[2][0];
    $int3=$matches[3][0];
    print "($int1) (-) ($int2) (-) ($int3) \n";
}
```

Note that I removed the grouping around the `-` since those stay constant. You can walk through this regex step-by-step at [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%5Cd%2b%29-%28%5Cd%2b%29-%28%5Cd%2b%29&str=12-345-689900).